# How to connect a command to the action of removing a nfc card from the reader?

Tags: nfc

I'm currently working on a project at work, where the employees can log in and logout from their accounts - with **an NFC card**.

My Idea was that they lay their card on a reader *(Acr 122u)* to open a URL with their **username** and **password**. I've already successfully got that by saving a URL to the card including the website followed by `login.do?userName=(...)&password=(...)`.

Now I want either the Browser to close, or *- if that's not possible -* another URL with the `logout.do` command to open, as soon as the card is removed from the reader. So nobody can forget to log out.

My problem is that I don't know how to link the logout command to the card removal action.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible and it sounds highly insecure. Any NFC scanner could get any person's username and password simply by being within range of the card. That information stored on a card is easy to duplicate. That means people with an NFC-capable smartphone could scan another person's card and use the information for malicious purposes.

However, An NFC card has a unique serial number which (usually) cannot be duplicated. It is commonly used for access control in some environments but not in the way you describe. If you wrote software for your computers which polls the NFC reader to check information about what (if any) card is currently readable by the device, you could then use the card's serial number to determine which employee it is and use that to open a browser window. The browser would need to be controlled by your software so it can also close that same browser window when the application no fails to detect a card after a certain number of seconds. Polling every second should be fine, and treating the card as missing after two or three failed checks would probably be enough to make sure the employee's browser doesn't close just because the reader was bumped.

The API reference is available from the manufacturer. https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/

Comment: Thank you, that sounds better.